# Yarn-site.xml changes not reflecting

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

We have an application managed by yarn when we change yarn-site.xml those changes are not reflected , application is still running with old configuration. We are new to Yarn any help in this regard will be helpful

**Note** : we have already tried restarted yarn using **stop-yarn.sh** and **start-yarn.sh** also restared dfs using **start-dfs.sh** and **stop-dfs.sh** . We are using hadoop 2.7.3

this is what yarn looks with only max memory configured to 16GB as shown in the picture but actual configuration is 22GB as per yarn-site.xml

[image: Yarn configuration]

this is the yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>hdfs-name-node</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>21528</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
        <value>6</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>21528</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs</name>
        <value>file:///tmp/hadoop/data/nm-local-dir,file:///tmp/hadoop/data/nm-local-dir/filecache,file:///tmp/hadoop/data/nm-local-dir/usercache</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms</name>
        <value>500</value>
    </property>
    <property>
         <name>yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.target-size-mb</name>
         <value>512</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

this is the node configuration

```
1 Master/Driver Node : 
  Memory :24GB Cores :8 

4 Worker Nodes : 
  Memory :24GB Cores :8
```

Comment: By any chance do you these properties set in the application as well? If yes, application set properties will take precedence!

Comment: these are properties are set only through yarn-site.xml not through application adding additional info to the question

Comment: The same property file is present in all nodes?

Comment: yes same property file present on all nodes checked it twice

Comment: In the URL `http://<resourcemanager_ip>:8088/conf` you will be able to see all the effective properties of the cluster. Search for `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` property, and the value of `<source>` tag. It will give the name of the file which is setting this value.

Comment: nice idea but it gave source as java.io.BufferedInputStream@327b636c :(

Comment: Is this setup created with ClouderaManager?

Comment: no it's apache hadoop 2.7.3